# Broken addEventListener method for cookie popup

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I need advice on how to fix the addEventListener function in the js cookie code for my website. The cookie popup always appears, but when I click the Agree button, it doesn't disappear and is not written to local storage. The console writes me this: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null". I would like someone to help me with this, I don't know how to deal with it. Below the text is the js code and the html code.

JS Code:

```
const cookieContainer = document.querySelector(".cookie-container");
const cookieButton = document.querySelector(".cookie-btn");

cookieButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  cookieContainer.classList.remove("active");
  localStorage.setItem("cookieBannerDisplayed", "true");
});

setTimeout(() => {
  if (!localStorage.getItem("cookieBannerDisplayed")) {
    cookieContainer.classList.add("active");
  }
}, 2000);
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="cookie-container">
        <p>
            Používáním této stránky souhlasíte s ukládáním souborů cookies a sběrem dat.
        </p>
        <button class="cookie-btn">Souhlasím</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/bp14kmaz/

Comment: Where did you place your script? Try placing it right before the closing body tag.

Comment: @Unmitigated 
The pop-up will be displayed when I go to the page, but if I want to agree with the cookies conditions, it does not work, the popup will not disappear and it will not be written to the local storage.

Comment: Where did you place the script element? I cannot reproduce the issue; your code works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/bp14kmaz/

Comment: I placed it at the top of the html code with the tag <script src ....> </script> @Unmitigated

Comment: You should place it before the closing the body tag instead. Otherwise, the elements won't be present at the time the script runs.

Comment: Inserting a script tag before the end of the wonder with a popup helped but only half to the local storage is loaded after pressing the button I agree the value true but the popup does not disappear. @Unmitigated

Comment: And no error is displayed in the console @Unmitigated

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. It works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/bp14kmaz/

Comment: Please check that link and add more code to it to show the issue.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Jakubeich/9yft5pzu/1/  Here it is @Unmitigated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the container's default display to `none` and only set it to `block` when it has the active class.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nx603v2d/)

Comment: thanks a lot it works but I would just like to ask how to move the popup so that it is up and down? @Unmitigated

Answer (score 0):

suggestion:

```js
if(cookieButton) {
  cookieButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    cookieContainer.classList.remove("active");
    localStorage.setItem("cookieBannerDisplayed", "true");
  });
}

// Edit:
setTimeout(() => {
  if (!localStorage.getItem("cookieBannerDisplayed")) {
   if(cookieContainer)
    cookieContainer.classList.add("active");
  }
}, 2000);
```

I presume if accepted, your div is not in the dom of the page. So unable to find your button.

```html
<div class="cookie-container">
...
</div>
```

Comment: It reports an error again: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null in setTimeout

Comment: Just edit my post you need to check also if "cookieContainer" exist